# How to start a .js file after it is stopped

Tags: javascript, node.js

i was looking to make a file / script that will restart a .js file after it has been stopped. after it is stopped, i want the new file to enter a command somewhere along the lines of this: `nodejs server.js`in my VPS window .

so what i am getting at is like this:

1) i have my server.js up and running on my VPS with the command; `nodejs server.js`

2) it will automatically stop (I have this part down)

3) i want to have another script that restarts the node.js server after it has been stopped.

sorry if i am jumbling my words, or asking a silly question, just not sure how to go about this!

Thanks!

Comment: There are some existing tools for this purpose – [`forever`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever), [`nodemon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon). (For some analysis of them, try [Comparison: Tools to Automate Restarting Node.js Server After Code Changes](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/comparison-tools-to-automate-restarting-node-js-server-after-code-changes-forever-nodemon-nodesupervisor-nodedev/))

Comment: thanks @JonathanLonowski ! the only problem now is that i get this error;


`[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...` 

any way to fix this?

Comment: **UPDATE** thanks i got it working! just a brain fart lol! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- install module **node-cmd** in project directory
- suppose you have too file server.js and app.js which listen on two different port
- keep both file in same directory(not mandatory but to run with out path confusion )

> server.js

```
const app = require('express')();


app.get('/',function(req,res){

res.send("running");
});
 var cmd=require('node-cmd');

   cmd.run('node server.js');

app.listen(8080);

console.log('listening on port 8080');
```

> app.js

```
const app = require('express')();


app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.send("support file which will start server.js");
});

 var cmd=require('node-cmd');

   cmd.run('node server.js');

app.listen(8090);

console.log('listening on port 8090');
```

call app.js when you want to run server.js

Answer (score 0):

nodemon usage is for when you change your server code or any code of your project then automaticaly restart server so when the app crashed it does not restart your server.js until you dont have a change in your codes so you need to use a package like forever or pm2 that start server continuously forever and if your app crashs then they will restart your server.js just after a few miliseconds here is the documentation :

https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/